# Dúvida código em Perl

Tags: perl

O seguinte código retornou erro na execução. Alguém saberia me dizer onde está o erro e como corrigi-lo?
Desde já, obrigada.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

for ($i=1; $i<15; $i = $i + 1;){
    for ($j=1; $j<15; $j = $j + 1;){
        $multi = $i * $j;
        print "$i X $j = $multi;\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual erro? aparce alguma mensagem?

Comment: Parecido ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181381/how-to-print-variables-in-perl

Comment: for ($i=1; $i<15; $i = $i + 1;){
    for ($j=1; $j<15; $j = $j + 1;){
        $multi = $i * $j;
        print "i*j = $multi /n";
        }
    }

Comment: Não manjo muito a sintaxe do perl, parece estar sobrando pontos e vírgulas nos argumentos... Mas o melhor a fazer é aprender a interpretar as mensagens de erro, segue a dica do amigo e coloca a mensagem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá.

Você errou nessa linhas: `for ($j=1; $j<15; $j = $j + 1;)` e `for ($i=1; $i<15; $i = $i + 1;)`

### A solução:

```perl
#
#  Perl
#
for ($i=1; $i<15;$i++){
    for ($j=1; $j<15;$j++){
        $multi = $i * $j;
        print "$i X $j = $multi;\n";
    }
}
```

### Console:

```
1 X 1 = 1;
1 X 2 = 2;
1 X 3 = 3
...
```

#### OBS: Não coloquei todos os valores,porque são muitos.

Comment: Caro Maury, seu script vai dar erro do mesmo jeito: `Unmatched right curly bracket at prog.pl line 9, at end of line
syntax error at prog.pl line 9, near "}"`

Comment: Foi teclado do celular 

Answer (score 2):

O seu código tem 2 **virgulas sobrando** em cada `for`, é erro de digitação, aqui antes dos parenteses tem um ponto e virgula:

```
for ($i=1; $i<15; $i = $i + 1;){
```

Especificamente este: `1;){`

Corrigido:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

for ($i=1; $i<15; $i = $i + 1){
    for ($j=1; $j<15; $j = $j + 1){
        $multi = $i * $j;
        print "$i X $j = $multi;\n";
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/wOidqS)

Comment: nenhuma linguagem m aceita isso. `$i+1;`

Comment: Caro @MauryDeveloper não tem nada haver com o `+1;` ... o `for` espera tres operações `for (<inicial>; <condição>; <após terminar o item atual>)`, quando ela colocou uma terceira `;`, o interpretador Perl não entendeu, pq não existe uma quarta operação e acusou erro de sintaxe, que é basicamente algo que foi digitado errado (erro de digitação)

Comment: Eu falei isso. Maioria usar três argumentos e não 4. Java,javascript e Perl. `;` confundir qualquer linguagem de 3 argumentos.

Comment: Caro @MauryDeveloper a pergunta não é sobre outras linguagens, a pergunta é sobre Perl e a resposta explica, esta sobrando um `;` em cada for.

Comment: Eu estou usando exemplos de outras linguagens. Se fiz algo errado me desculpe.